# Reemplazar caracter por su opuesto

Tags: python

Perdone por el título, no se como explicarlo mejor.
Estoy aprendiendo a programar en python y estoy intentando crear un codificador para que para cada letra del mensaje que introduzca, me devuelva la letra opuesta en el alfabeto.

Para poder explicar mejor el problema aquí está lo que llevo de código:

```
Input=input("Introduzca el mensaje: ")
Mensaje=Input.lower()

Mensaje1=(Mensaje.replace("a","z").replace("b","y").replace("c","x")
    .replace("d","w").replace("e","v").replace("f","u").replace("g","t")
    .replace("h","s").replace("i","r").replace("j","q").replace("k","p")
    .replace("l","o").replace("m","ñ").replace("n","n").replace("ñ","m")
    .replace("o","l").replace("p","k").replace("q","j").replace("r","i")
    .replace("s","h").replace("t","g").replace("u","f").replace("v","e")
    .replace("w","d").replace("x","c").replace("y","b").replace("z","a"))

print(Mensaje1)
```

Y este es el resultado de meter ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ en la consola como input:

```
Introduzca el mensaje: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ
abcdefghijklmnmlkjihgfedcba

***Repl Closed***
```

El problema es que va en orden haciendo el "replace", por lo que como al principio ha cambiado la "a" a "z", al final transforma la "z" a "a".

¿Sabrían decirme cómo solucionar este problema de tal forma que una vez hecho el cambio, no se pueda volver a cambiar?

Perdonen la extensión de la pregunta. Es la primera vez que pregunto algo por aquí y no se muy bien como se hace. Agradezco cualquier sugerencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lo que quieres hacer Python tiene una función específica, que es `translate()`. El problema es que es un poco más complicada de usar de lo que debiera, pues hay que pasarle una "tabla de traducción" con las parejas de caracteres a "traducir" (el de "entrada" y el de "salida"). Esta tabla se crea con ayuda de otra función llamada `maketrans()`.

Este sería el código:

```
abecedario = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz"
tabla = str.maketrans(abecedario, abecedario[::-1])

msg = input("Introduzca el mensaje: ")
msg = msg.lower()
msg = msg.translate(tabla)
print(msg)
```

Observa cómo usé el operador de slice para obtener el abecedario "invertido" y así no tener que escribirlo a mano.

### Solución más artesanal

Si no quieres hacer uso de `str.tanslate()` puedes hacerlo mediante un bucle, pero para evitar que una vez reemplezada una letra se te vuelva a reemplazar, debes usar diferentes variables para la entrada y la salida.

Iteras por cada letra del mensaje de entrada, y guardas la letra "opuesta" en una lista que será el mensaje de salida. Al final conviertes esa lista en cadena mediante `str.join()`

Para hacer la solución más general, haré una función `cifrar_letra()` que reciba una letra y te devuelva la letra "cifrada" (que en este caso sería la "invertida" según el alfabeto, pero que puedes cambiar para que use otros tipos de cifrado, como el césar).

Para implementar la función que te da la letra cifrada puedes montar un diccionario de traducción, que contenga para cada letra cuál sería su versión cifrada, o hacer algo como en `maketrans()`, que reciba dos cadenas y las use para convertir la letra de una de las cadenas a la que ocupa la misma posición en la otra. Usaré este segundo enfoque:

```
def cifrar_letra(letra, abecedario_origen, abecedario_destino):
    if letra not in abecedario_origen:
      return letra                     # Las no previstas no las modifica
    indice = abecedario.index(letra)
    return abecedario_destino[indice]
```

Apoyándote en esta función podrías codificar tu cifrado así:

```
abecedario = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz"
inverso = abecedario[::-1]
msg = input("Introduzca el mensaje: ")
msg = msg.lower()

cifrado = []
for letra in msg:
  cifrado.append(cifrar_letra(letra, abecedario, inverso))

cifrado = "".join(cifrado)  # Convertir la lista en cadena
print(cifrado)
```

### Bonus

La misma función antes vista te permite hacer otros cifrados, como el Cesar que consiste en cambiar cada letra por la que está N posiciones después, por ejemplo para N=5 podrías hacer:

```
abecedario = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz"
cesar_5 = abecedario[5:] + abecedario[:5]
```

y luego llamar a `cifrar_letra(letra, abecedario, cesar_5)`

Answer (score 1):

No tienes que hacer ese monton de replaces para cambiar la letra por la "opuesta". Solo tienes que saber en qué posición (indice) está el caracter en la cadena de referencia y luego hacer el cálculo de la `longitud total - el indice` para saber su "opuesto".

```
>>> ref = "abcde"
>>> "e".index(ref)
4
```

En python las cadenas son iterables, así que puedes iterar sobre ella para hacer los cálculos sobre cada elemento.

```
usr_in = input("Introduzca el mensaje: ").lower()
abc = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz"

long_abc = len(abc)
opuesto = ""
for char in usr_in:
    idx = abc.index(char)
    opuesto += abc[long_abc - idx - 1]

print(opuesto)
```

Hay potenciales problemas con el código: Solo sirve con cadenas alfabéticas. Si se introducen numeros, espacios, coma, punto y otros caracteres la ejecución fallará.

Una forma de solucionar eso sería que si no se encuentra el caracter en la referencia, devolver ese caracter sin convertir.

```
for char in usr_in:
    try:
        idx = abc.index(char)
        opuesto += abc[long_abc - idx - 1]
    except:
        opuesto += char
```

Answer (score 0):

*(El lenguaje lo desconozco)* Tu proceso es el que esta fallando; esto se debe a que tratas todas la cadena con el `replace` cuando debes obtener letra por letra, **codificarla** y pasar a la siguiente; lo que hace es por ejemplo

1. Recibes `Mensaje1="az"`
2. La codificas con:

```
Mensaje1=(Mensaje
    .replace("a","z") /* Codificas */
    .replace("b","y").replace("c","x")
    .replace("d","w").replace("e","v").replace("f","u").replace("g","t")
    .replace("h","s").replace("i","r").replace("j","q").replace("k","p")
    .replace("l","o").replace("m","ñ").replace("n","n").replace("ñ","m")
    .replace("o","l").replace("p","k").replace("q","j").replace("r","i")
    .replace("s","h").replace("t","g").replace("u","f").replace("v","e")
    .replace("w","d").replace("x","c").replace("y","b")
    .replace("z","a") /* Codificas */
)
```

El 1er y último replace se aplica a todos; es decir con el 1er `replace` `Mensaje.replace("a","z")` da como resultado `Mensaje1="zz"` y con el último `replace` queda `Mensaje1="aa"`
3. Al finalizar obtienes `Mensaje1="aa"`

Lo que debes hacer es tomar desde la primer letra hasta la ultima y **codificarla**; es decir asumiendo (de nuevo) `Mensaje="az"`; seria:

1. Inicializar `Mensaje1=""` (como cadena vacía).
2. Tomas la primer letra que es `a` codificarla (obtendrias) `z`como resultado. La agregas a `Mensaje1` para que sea `Mensaje1="z"`.
3. Tomas la segunda letra que es `z` y la codificas (obtendrias) `a` como resultado. La agregas a `Mensaje1` para que sea `Mensaje1="za"`.

De tal forma que así obtienes que ya codificado `Mensaje="za"`